# How to find the index of an arraylist item, using a property in a list item?

Tags: java, apache-commons, android-guava

//what is the best way to find out the index of a particular event using the Offer Id?
        using core java or using a third-party library like (Guava/Commons Collection)?

```
  public class Event{
        private String title;
        //other attributes
        private ArrayList<Offers> lOffers;
    }

    public class Offers{
        private Sring Id;
        private String offerName;
    }


    //Code
    List<PayPerViewTitles>  PayPerViewTitleList = someMethod();

/*

offerId -> Offers Object id property
**/
    private int findEventPositionByOfferId(List<Event> eventList, String offerId){
       // how to implement this method to find the Main Event using the 
       offer->id
    }
```

This Object is used to Map the server JSON Response,

Comment: Before trying to find the best way, have you at least tried **a** way? Why don't you respect the Java naming conventions?

Comment: And where this offerId is present?

Comment: Any specific reason `lOffers` should be a list? Did you consider using some other data structure?

Comment: That question is most likely going to be primarily opinion based. I think this would fit better at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a map to save id as key,object as value,then use list,like this:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    Student student0 = Student.builder().id(1).name("wentjiang").age(23).build();
    Student student1 = Student.builder().id(2).name("wentjiang2").age(232).build();

    Map<Integer,Student> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(student0.getId(),student0);
    map.put(student1.getId(),student1);
    students.add(student0);
    students.add(student1);
    Integer findId = 2;
    Student student = map.get(findId);
    int index = students.indexOf(student);
    System.out.println(index);
```